# How to generate type checking in JavaScript at run time?

Tags: javascript, types, typescript, typechecking, flowtype

With TypeScript or Facebook's Flow(type) I can statically type variables like

```
function add (x: integer, y: integer) { ... }
```

Both TypeScript and Flow catch any illegal invocation such as `add('1',0)` at **compile time**.

However, when the library is compiled and exported, the types are gone. That means, the library consumer using that function gets no errors, that may potentially lead to hard-to-debug problems.

Is there any way to auto-generate additional code that would throw exactly the same errors at run time?

I can surely manually place guards every time a typecheck is expected but that feels boring and repetitive.

Comment: Is this a flowtype question, or a typescript question?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'd be happy to use either or any other technology that solves the problem.

Comment: JS is a dynamically typed language. Don't try to make something out of the language, what it isn't. Otherwise you would mimic a compiling step for EVERY request. That's insane. Apply unit tests intensively instead. Unit tests are the replacement for the missing compiler in JS.

Comment: @Iven Amazingly both TypeScript and FB Flowtype are doing exactly that. With unit tests being around all this time.

Comment: I've been working on a runtime type checker for Javascript for quite a while now. It is quite different from TS/Flow, though, because it supports parametric and row poylmorphism instead of subtyping. And it is still experimental. You can find a link to the repo on my profile page, if you're interested.

Comment: @ftor Could you provide a link here, I could not find it?

Comment: Sure, [type checker](https://github.com/kongware/ftor)

Comment: @ftor Thanks, interesting project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/codemix/babel-plugin-typecheck does what you want.

There is also https://gcanti.github.io/flowcheck/ but it looks a bit abandoned.

I haven't personally used any of those libraries. It seems that they might cover less than 100% of Flow syntax.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, please provide explanation!

Comment: [babel-plugin-typecheck](https://github.com/codemix/babel-plugin-typecheck) is now deprecated ... [flow-runtime](https://codemix.github.io/flow-runtime/) is the recommended successor.

Comment: And [flow-runtime is no longer really maintained either](https://github.com/gajus/flow-runtime#maintenance-status).

Answer (score 1):

You won't get that from javascript alone regardless of which you choose as javascript doesn't have the notion of types in this sense.

I've never worked with fb flow so I can't reply on that, but typescript-wise here are the options I think you have: (in order of complexity and how much it doesn't make sense)

1. **Modify the typescript compiler to automatically add runtime parameters validation**
   You can [use the compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) and inject a piece of code that validate the params for the functions.  The compiler will tell you what the param names and types are, if they are optional and so on.
   *I'm just including this as an option but it's a pretty messed up solution in my opinion.*
2. **Start every function with validation**
   Pretty much like the previous one, just that you'll include the code yourself in each function instead of modifying the compiler to do so.
   You can have a global function that take as arguments the meta data of the declared params and the actual arguments that are passed.
   *This will make things pretty ugly code-wise, and won't be fun to maintain.*
3. **In case of classes you can use decorators**
   [The decorators feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) is pretty new, but typescript lets you use it, and if you want to do this validation thing on classes then this is the best solution for your problem so far.
4. **Generate a definition file for you library**
   This is the best of options if you ask me.
   You don't need to contaminate your code with checks in each function. More than that, you can never control who's using your lib or how they use it so it's lost cause to even try.
   For this your lib consumers will need to write in typescript themselves.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such detailed answer! 1) looks intimidating indeed but good to know it exits; 2) doesn't sound fun indeed and would bloat my tests unfortunately; 3) looks very interesting, I don't have much experience with decorators, the last example (in the handbook decorators page) does not really say what exactly will happen, would be great to see more detailed explanation; 4) I see your point, sadly it would lock any consumer into TS or risk unpredictable results (`11` vs `2` when adding `'1' + 1`).

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, please provide explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [babel-plugin-runtyper](https://github.com/vitalets/babel-plugin-runtyper) that performs type checking in runtime and does not require manual annotations.
For your example, if function looks like:

```
function add(x, y) {
   return x + y;
}
```

And you call it as

```
add('1', 0);
```

you will get warning in console:

> Plus operation with different types: "1" (string) + 0 (number)

Comment: Nice tool, especially that no code change is needed -- neat!